# IE color <dt> spill

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have made a page [here](http://www.souslecharme.ca/consommations.html)

the DT title is underline red with text white... in firefox everything is fine... but the dt spill in IE... why ?

here is a [VIEW](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/5848c1d17cf9be96ee818e7a26844d35/) of the problem !

Here is the perfect example of WHAT is [the problem](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/662d9cbb543d3b95346af83de8c062fd/)

[alt text http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/66/662d9cbb543d3b95346af83de8c062fd.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/66/662d9cbb543d3b95346af83de8c062fd.png)

Comment: I see no difference from Firefox in IE 8 both with and without Compatibility View.  Which version of IE does the problem happen in?

Comment: IE6 PC everything undet the title is the SAME color as the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <h1>Nos consommations</h1>
```

You can't just put any old element inside any other. `<h1>`, `<h2>` and the `<dt>`​s are quite invalid as children of `<ul>` and the browser will try to cope by fixing up your markup, and not all browsers deal with mistakes in the same way.

What may be happening with IE here is that it is ‘fixing’ the `<li>` following the red-backgrounded-`<dt>` by assuming you meant to have a `<ul>` inside the `<dt>` itself. Hence the red background expands to cover the rest of the list, and the font colour inherits.

To stop this kind of thing happening, use the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: you are right (the w3.org) told me so... i will redo the whole thing with <dl> <dt> and <dd> and it will be fix (i hope)